# Что такое контекст в Python?

Tags: python, терминология

Часто в статьях про Python встречаю словосочетание

> контекстный менеджер

Решил статьи почитать про то, что такое контекстный менеджер. Там пишут

> Когда Python встречает оператор with, он создает новый контекст. При
> желании контекст может возвращать объект.

И

> Менеджер контекста — это объект, определяющий контекст выполнения в
> операторе with.

Везде говорят про некий контекст. Смотрю что такое контекст в Python, не нахожу, там только про контекстной менеджер говорят. Объясните пожалуйста что это такое?

Comment: Контекст - объект типа "контекстный менеджер".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Простыми словами, не обязательно про программирование, контекст - это то, с чем мы в данный момент работаем, текущая ситуация. В программировании этот термин может использоваться как абстрактное понятие, а не именно какие-то объекты или классы.

Для примера, при работе с файлами вы открываете файл через `open` в блоке `with`:

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Вы получаете объект файла, и при выходе из блока `with` файл автоматически закрывается (в том числе, если выход из блока произошел из-за какой-то ошибки). При этом сам объект файла (без блока `with`) не является контекстом, т.к. при простом открытии файла без блока `with` вы получите точно такой же объект файла, но файл закроется автоматически только при завершении программы, вам нужно вручную закрыть его (как бы "выйти из контекста", вручную управлять контекстом).

При использовании конструкции `with` вы не вручную управляете контекстом (например, не закрываете файл явно), а за вас это делает менеджер контекста.

Контекст в данном случае - это именно абстрактное понятие. Менеджер контекста - это не контекст, это объект который буквально управляет ("manage") контекстом, для Python - выполняет предварительные и завершающие действия, чтобы войти и выйти из контекста (например, открывает файл при входе в блок `with` и закрывает файл при выходе из блока).

Также в программировании контекстом может называться некий объект, который хранит текущее состояние программы (или части программы, например, функции или объекта). Для методов классов контекстом можно считать сам объект класса, от которого они вызываются, либо какое-то поле, которое описывает текущую ситуацию, с которой мы работаем, например модель для контроллера.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers Проще говоря, Менеджер контекста объект который имеет методы `__enter__(self)` и `__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)` а `with` вызывает сначала `__enter__` и в конце `__exit__` если происходит ошибка то `with` передаёт её в `__exit__`.
К примеру код:

```py
with EXPRESSION as TARGET:
    SUITE
```

Можно заменить так:

```py
manager = (EXPRESSION)
enter = type(manager).__enter__
exit = type(manager).__exit__
value = enter(manager)
hit_except = False

try:
    TARGET = value
    SUITE
except:
    hit_except = True
    if not exit(manager, *sys.exc_info()):
        raise
finally:
    if not hit_except:
        exit(manager, None, None, None)
```